# What is the difference between 約款{やっかん} and 契約{けいやく}?

Tags: meaning, dictionary

What is the difference between 約款{やっかん} and 契約{けいやく}?

**As per dictionary the following are the meanings**

> 約款 - agreement; article; clause 
>   契約 - contract; agreement

These words are used in the Insurance domain. So please explain the differences with examples?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

契約 is the contract itself.
約款 are clauses/articles to which you agreed on the contract.

Here is an example use/explanation of the word 約款.

> 保険や運送など不特定多数の利用者との契約を処理するため、あらかじめ定型的に定められた契約条項。

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%B4%84%E6%AC%BE-648590